# UIView reflect CALayer properties

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, core-animation

When changing a UIView's basic view properties (eg backgroundColor, alpha/opacity, frame) is it actually the layer that get's those changes under the hood? To put it simple, when I change the UIViews alpha for example is it actually the CALayers opacity property that changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, views are fairly thin wrappers around layers, and most view properties like the frame/bounds, alpha, etc. are indeed just manipulating the underlying layer. You can verify your alpha example with a little snippet of code in a view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.view.alpha = 0.5f;
    NSLog(@"Layer alpha: %f", self.view.layer.opacity);

    self.view.layer.opacity = 1.0f;
    NSLog(@"View alpha: %f", self.view.alpha);
}
```

This prints out:

```
Layer alpha: 0.500000
View alpha: 1.000000
```

So we can see that the view alpha and layer opacity are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks Mike can you also explain when to use what? I read somewhere that "UIView for controls, Layers for eyecandy". What is your thinking of this?

Comment: Views are easier. Use View animation whenever possible. The new methods of the form animateWithDuration:animation: are clean and easy to use. View animation gets complex fast. As for changing view/layer properties like background color, I don't think it matters that much.